# Elasticsearch.NET version 7 - How to Check If Index Exists

Tags: nest, elasticsearch.net

In Elasticsearch.NET 6.x, it is possible to check if index exists using `IElasticClient` method:

```cs
    bool exists = elasticClient.IndexExists("my-index-name").Exists;
```

Method is removed in Elasticsearch.NET version 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Elasticsearch.NET version 7 methods related to indices operations are moved into `IndicesNamespace`, so `IndexExists` method has been moved to:

```cs
    bool exists = elasticClient.Indices.Exists("my-index-name").Exists;
```

Similarly, different methods have been moved to:

- Cat
- Cluster
- Graph
- Sql
- Nodes
- etc...